# Using D3 Queue to make a cross site call

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xmlhttprequest, queue

I have my queue setup like

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "js/US.json")
.defer(d3.json, "http://192.168.1.40:8080/api/2014", function(d) { dataSet.set(d.id, +d.plant); })
.defer(d3.csv, "data/ph.csv", function(d) { phById.set(d.id, +d.ph); })
.awaitAll(ready);
```

However, my ready function is never called. I have no errors in my console. I've done checks to make sure my data is being returned and that my dataSet is loaded with the proper data. I'm not understanding why my queue never calls my ready function. Any direction here would be really appreciated.

Comment: Ian, queue.js is not D3, it's a different library.

Comment: Queue is provided by Mike Bostock and used mainly by d3.js users. I would like to keep those tags in there so d3 users might find my post.

Comment: I don't see what that's going to help, but if you insist on it, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue.defer()` function passes an additional callback argument to the task function passed to it, which must be called by the task function upon completion. In your case, you are calling the `d3.json` task function, and handing it two arguments, plus the additional callback argument (thanks to `queue.defer`).

The `d3.json` method expects two arguments - a url and a callback. It will receive three arguments, but only use the first two. As such, the callback function from `queue.defer()` won't be invoked, and the `queue.awaitAll()` function never sees the tasks as completed.

You need to pass the results from each .json and .csv task to a final callback function:

```
queue().defer(d3.json, "js/US.json")
       .defer(d3.json, "http://192.168.1.40:8080/api/2014")
       .defer(d3.csv, "data/ph.csv")
       .awaitAll(ready);

function ready(error, result1, result2, result3) {
  //do some things with your results here - these are the results passed
  //from each task.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I can't believe I didn't try this while messing around trying to get it to work.